# Invalid MongoDB connection string in database URL

Tags: mongodb, prisma, mongodb-atlas

I am trying to write a Nuxt3 app using prisma and atlas MongoDB, I successfully set up all and `npx prisma db push` works fine, But when I send queries to your database I get the following error:

```json
"message": "\nInvalid `prisma.user.create()` invocation:\n\n\nThe provided 
database string is invalid. MongoDB connection string error: invalid connection 
string scheme: mongo in database URL. Please refer to the documentation in 
https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/database-reference/connection-urls for 
constructing a correct connection string. In some cases, certain characters must 
be escaped. Please check the string for any illegal characters.",
```

### Files

```
// .env file
DATABASE_URL="mongodb+srv://<USER>:<PASS>@cluster0.<ID>.mongodb.net/nuxt-app"
```

```
// schema.prisma
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mongodb"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model User {
  id           String  @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  username     String  @unique
  password     String
}
```

```js
// users.js
import { prisma } from ".";

export const createUser = (userData) => {
    return prisma.user.create({
        data: UserData
    })
}
```

i am using

```json
"nuxt": "^3.2.3"
"prisma": "^4.11.0"
```

Comment: Maybe your password has some special characters, i.e. `: / ? # [ ] @`. In this case you need to escape them, `encodeURIComponent()`

Comment: the password contains only letters and numbers.

Comment: the problem is that `npx prisma db push` accept the connection string and create collections in db , but when I try to make a query it said that the connection string is invalid

Comment: I am having the same problem, where you able to find a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the string is probably missing a collection name

```
DATABASE_URL="mongodb+srv://<user>:<pass>@<cluster_name>/<colection_name>?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
```